# Why is my jQuery-generated list item not displaying?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have an XML file named Platypus.XML that I've added to my Razor 2 project on the same level as the files supplied by default when creating a new Razor 2 website in VS 2012 (_AppStart.cshtml, Default.cshtml, etc.)

The XML file seems to be well-formed (besides, it is used successfully elsewhere):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Platypi>
  <Platypus>
    <PlatypusNumber>1</PlatypusNumber>
    <LocationNumber>1</LocationNumber>
    <PlatypusName>CCR, Inc. Site 1 Q &amp; A</PlatypusName>
  </Platypus>
. . .
</Platypi>
```

I've got this html and jQuery:

```
. . .
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Platypus.XML" />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="Get Platypus2.XML" />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup2"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="three">
        <input type="submit" id="submit3" value="Get Platypus3.XML"  />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup3"></div>
    </li>
</ol>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Platypus.XML",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (PlatypusRec) {
                        var platypusSetup = "<ul>";
                        $(PlatypusRec).find('Platypus').each(function () {
                            var platypusNum = $(this).find('PlatypusNumber').text()
                            platypusSetup += "<li>" + platypusNum + "</li>";
                        });
                        platypusSetup += "</ul>";
                        $('#Platypus_Setup').append(platypusSetup);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

(I adapted this from the aPress book "jQuery Recipes", recipe 8-8)

Nevertheless, mashing the "Get Platypus.XML" button does not append anything to the Platypus_Setup div element. It doesn't throw an error, either, it just does absolutely nothing (that I can see).

What am I missing here?

### UPDATE

In response to LOUD's suggestion to "hit the file manually":

Changing the URL from:

```
http://localhost:53321/XMLFileViewer/Default.cshtml
```

to:

```
http://localhost:53321/XMLFileViewer/PLATYPUS.XML
```

...displays the XML file, but also the message at the top:

*This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.*

Also, I added the error code just above the "return false;" line:

```
error: function (xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.status);
}
return false;
```

...but I'm not sure if that's the right spot, as the "status" is grayed out; running it and mashing the button with the new exception handler does nothing different (I see no alert box)...

### UPDATE 2

Moving the exception block above:

```
error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                }
                });
                return false;
```

...bolded up "status" in VS2012, but there's still no err msg on mashing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper, jsFiddle and [Are these problems caught by jsFiddle causing the click event to malfunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174165/are-these-problems-caught-by-jsfiddle-causing-the-click-event-to-malfunction/16174216?noredirect=1#16174216) helped me to clean up the jQuery; once I got the syntax correct, it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "DuckbillSETUP.XML",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (platypusSetupRec) {
                    var platypussetup = "<ul>";
                    $(platypusSetupRec).find('platypus').each(function () {
                        var platypusNum = $(this).find('platypusNumber').text();
                        platypussetup += "<li>" + platypusNum + "</li>";
                    });
                    platypussetup += "</ul>";
                    $('#platypus_Setup').append(platypussetup);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, change $(Platypus) to $(PlatypusRec) in the code below:

```
success: function (PlatypusRec) {
    var platypusSetup = "<ul>";
    $(Platypus).find('Platypus')
```

Also, which files are you talking about (views/controller/etc)? Depending on your routing it may not be picking it up.

> I have an XML file named Platypus.XML that I've added to my Razor 2 project on the same level as the files supplied by default when creating a new Razor 2 website

I would try hitting the file manually in the browser from the same path. I would also add a failure event to try catching server status codes (404, 500, etc)

```
error: function(xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.status); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part - those two vals are the same in my code (I fixed the original post now to reflect that). As to "which files", this is a very simple utility and I'm not (deliberately) using the MVC pattern. The XML file has simply been added directly to the project at the root.

Comment: It may be a permissions issue - If I understood it right/remember it correctly, I was reading last night that XML (and JSON) files can not normally (there's always an exception/hack) be accessed from a "file server" but must be accessed from a web server. But then again, this doesn't make a lot of sense to me - if you have access to the file, and have added it to your project, why you would not be able to read/process it...??? I must have misunderstood that...