# Are these problems caught by jsFiddle causing the click event to malfunction?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, jsfiddle

My jQuery compiles (and runs in the browser) using VS2012, but the click event is not doing what I want (it's not doing anything, actually, that I can see).

I added my html and jQuery into jsfiddle and ran "JSHint" on it. There are three places where it wags its virtual finger in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "DuckbillSETUP.XML",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (PlatypusSetupRec) {
                        var Platypussetup = "<ul>";
                        $(PlatypusSetupRec).find('Platypus').each(function () {
                            var PlatypusNum = $(this).find('PlatypusNumber').text()
                            Platypussetup += "<li>" + PlatypusNum + "</li>";
                        });
                        Platypussetup += "</ul>";
                        $('#Platypus_Setup').append(Platypussetup);
                    }
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

...namely:

```
var PlatypusNum = $(this).find('PlatypusNumber').text()
```

Where it says, "*Missing semicolon*"

```
error: function (xhr, status) {
```

Where it says, "*Missing name in function declaration*"

```
});
```

(last line) where it says, "*Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'*"

I don't grok just how to fix this jQuery, or if any of these things could be the reason clicking on the button does nothing.

Note: I *do* have a button with the id "Submit":

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get DuckbillSETUP.XML" />
        <div id="Platypus_Setup">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `,` before the `error:...`

```
}, // <-- add this comma
error: function (xhr, status) {
```

and add a `;` after

```
var PlatypusNum = $(this).find('PlatypusNumber').text(); //<-- add the missing ;
```